# Selenium webdriver,Java - Filling form opened in new tab

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I click on image, it opens form in new tab and there are some radio buttons to select and finish the form. I am able to open new tab and pass control to it but not able to click on radio buttons and finish form.I tried many way.

Comment: Foremost thing is, we need more information to help you out. We just said, tried many ways. What are those ? How do you say that the control passed over to the form ? What do you mean by not able to click ? _ What is the exception you are getting /

Comment: Tried many ways like 1. Using xpath locator of the radio button and click method.2. Using selectbyValue. I used 2 ways to pass control over to new tab like: 1. Set windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();Iterator it = windowHandles.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){System.out.println(it.next());}.and 2nd way used was  new Actions(wd).sendKeys(wd.findElement(By.tagName("html")),Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(wd.findElement(By.tagName("html")),Keys.NUMPAD2).build().perform();. I want to see radio button to be selected when I click on it and completed the form

Comment: What is the exception you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there's a new window opening, in WebDriver you must switch to windows or frames in-order to perform any operation

One best way to switch newly open window could be

```
Set<String> windowHandleSet = driver.getWindowHandles();
String[] windowHandles = new String[windowHandleSet.size()];
windowHandles = windowHandleSet.toArray(windowHandles);
driver.switchTo().window(windowHandles[windowHandleSet.size() - 1]);
```

After this code is invoked you can perform operation in your new window.